# Phonegap remove/delete taken image

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've been following the Phonegap [Camera Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html), and am uploading the `ImageURI` to a server successfully. However, the image that was cached when the photo was taken is still on the phone. How do I clear the cache or remove the photo after I'm done uploading the photo?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take the picture URI and pass it to window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI and then in the success callback of this method you will get a FileEntry object which you can call the remove method on.